# Library calls for converting timestruc_t to text or struct tm

Tags: c++, casting, localtime

I was writing a quick utility to dump out some of the details of the `stat` structure but hit an issue as the time attributes of `stat` seem to be of type `timestruc_t` which on my platform seems to be two 64bit ints.

```
struct stat statBuf;
return_code = stat( aFileName, &statBuf );
if ( !return_code )
{
    struct tm res;
    localtime_r( statBuf.st_mtim.tv_sec, &res ); // problem!
```

I thought I could maybe use `localtime_r` to convert the seconds attribute into a `struct tm` but I seem to get casting issues using `statBuf.st_mtim.tv_sec` as the first parameter.

I'm sure this isn't the best solution - maybe you know a better one. I just want to get the date and time - down to sub-seconds if possible - out as a string in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH.MM.SS.SSS` or something similar. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

**UPDATE**

This was a simple issue - my mistake. Just forgot that the first parameter needs to be the *address of* and `int` not the `int` by value. So the amended and partially completed code looks like this:

```
    localtime_r( &statBuf.st_mtim.tv_sec, &res );
    const int bufLen=24;
    char buffer[ bufLen + 1];
    strftime( buffer, bufLen, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &res );
    printf("  %s, %s\n", aFileName, buffer);
```

Comment: Just answered. See UPDATE above.

Comment: For extra "credits", you can add the solution as an answer and accept it. :)

Answer (score -1):

The first parameter needs to be the *address of* an `int` not the `int` by value.